# How to load module into python with argv

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I want to load oneRunParams.py into my current program but won't know where it is till I run it. I want to have it as an input argument, accessed through argv. I was using:

from oneRunParams import *

I now want to replace this with something that will do the same only with the path to oneRunParams specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`__import__`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__):

Here is `test.py`:

```
# test.py
import sys

filename = sys.argv[1]
f = __import__(filename[:-3]) # This removes the `.py` extension
f.test()
```

Here is `test2.py`:

```
# test2.py
def test():
    print('hello world')
```

Running the following the command line:

```
python test.py test2.py
```

Gives the following output:

```
hello world
```

If you really want to load everything in local scope, you have to do the following:

```
filename = sys.argv[1]
f = __import__(filename[:-3], globals(), locals(), ['*'])
for k in dir(f):
    locals()[k] = getattr(f, k)

test()
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this so that I can just call test() instead of f.test(). I know that this is not a preferred method, but I may need to do it this way due to other constraints.

Comment: How do I make it so that the filename includes the path to the file?

Comment: When you are calling the script, use `python file.py /home/usr/chris/folder/otherfile.py` etc. Just pass the absolute path of the file.

Answer (score 0):

```
from sys import argv
```

Use above statement.

```
fileName=argv[0]
```